# Python Recursion and list

Tags: python, recursion

I am learning about recursion in python and I have this code:

```
def search(l,key):
    """
    locates key in list l.  if present, returns location as an index; 
    else returns False.
    PRE: l is a list.
    POST: l is unchanged; returns i such that l[i] == key; False otherwise.
    """

    if l:   # checks if list exists
        if l[0] == key:     # base case - first index is key
            return True

        s = search(l[1:], key)      # recursion
        if s is not False:          
            return s

    return False            # returns false if key not found
```

Can someone explain to me what the line

```
s = search(l[1:], key)
```

does exactly? and what does l[1:] do to the list?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: humm, the code doesn't seem to `returns i such that l[i] == key`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual way to recursively traverse a list in functional programming languages is to use a function that accesses the first element of the list (named `car`, `first`, `head` depending on the language) and another function that accesses the rest of the list (`cdr`, `rest`, `tail`). In Python there isn't a direct equivalent to those functions, but we can to this for the same effect, using [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/201359):

```
lst[0]  # first element of a list
lst[1:] # rest of the elements in the list, after the first
```

For example, a recursive search function in Python that determines whether an element is or not in a list (a predicate, because it returns `True` or `False`) would look like this:

```
def search(lst, key):
    if not lst:         # base case: list is empty
        return False
    elif lst[0] == key: # base case: current element is searched element
        return True
    else:               # recursive case: advance to next element in list
        return search(lst[1:], key)
```

With the above example in mind, it's easy to adapt it to solve the original problem - how to return the index of an element in a list (if found) or `False` (if not found):

```
def search(l, key):
    if not l:
        return False
    elif l[0] == key:
        return 0
    else:
        idx = search(l[1:], key)
        return 1+idx if idx is not False else False
```

Comment: Thank you! I would upvote your answer but I dont have enough rep yet D:

Comment: Edit: It works for nested lists, but when I try it with this `search([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6 , [], [8, 9]], 10]], 8)` it doesnt return anything? oh and also I modified my code so that it returns true iff s is present in L

Comment: To add to the above comment, after some testing it only works for nested lists if the nested list is the last element in the list. I have no idea why this is happening D:

Comment: @NickGong the original question doesn't specify that the input list is nested, that leads to a completely different answer. Besides, how would the function be defined? for example, in a list such as `[1, [2, 3], 4]` what would be the index of `2`? is it `1`? is it `0`? you'll have to post it as a different question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input, I will post a different question!

Answer (score 3):

It recursively calls the `search` function, with the sliced data from `l`. `l[1:]` means all the data excluding the elements till the index `1`. For example,

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print data[1:]            # [2, 3, 4, 5]
print data[2:]            # [3, 4, 5]
```

You can use the slicing notation to get values between ranges, for example

```
print data[1:4]           # [2, 3, 4]
print data[2:3]           # [3]
```

You can also get all the elements till the specific index (excluding the element at the index)

```
print data[:4]           # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print data[:3]           # [1, 2, 3]
```

Sometimes you may not know the index of the elements from the end. So, you can use negative indices, like this

```
print data[-2:]          # [4, 5]
print data[1:-2]         # [2, 3]
print data[:-3]          # [1, 2]
```

When you use negative indices, the last element is represented with `-1`, last but one with `-2` and so on. You can read more about this slicing notation in this [excellent answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Oh, i see, so it just keeps using search on the elements and as it goes down it excludes index 0 every time?

Answer (score 1):

Cool. This is where the recursion happens (as you noted), by calling the function itself given the same `key` but a subset of the list `l` (the first element isn't included).

Basically, it will keep doing this until the `key` is found in the list. If so, `True` will be returned. Otherwise, the entire list will be gone over until the list is empty (all elements have been checked for equality with `key`. At that point, the algorithm gives up and returns `False`.

This will just tell you if the `key` is in the list but not what index can be found at.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case when recursion becomes handy (works for nested lists two):

```
def search_in_list(alist, elem):
    found = False
    for num in alist:
        if num == elem:
            return True
        if isinstance(num, list):
            found = search_in_list(num, elem)
            if found:
                return found
    return found

print(search_in_list([0, [1, [2], 3], [4, [5, [6, [7, [8]]]]]], 5))
```