# python recursive list questions

Tags: python, recursion

1.I came across this code: [Python Recursion and list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660346/python-recursion-and-list)

```
def search(lst, key):
    if not lst:         # base case: list is empty
        return False
    elif lst[0] == key: # base case: current element is searched element
        return True
    else:               # recursive case: advance to next element in list
        return search(lst[1:], key)
```

Can the recursive search start from the first element as `search(lst[0:],key)`? Why is the first element treated separately?

2.Why is this a recursion?

```
selfref_list = [1, 2, 3]
selfref_list.append(selfref_list)
```

Comment: Upvoted as it is a good question for those who are new to *recursion* in programming.

Comment: You don't have to make a comment about your upvote

Comment: 2. Isn't really a recursion, this is called a cyclic or circular object--an object that contains a reference to itself. In other words, your list contains a reference to itself and that's how it became cyclic.

Comment: I dare you to call `search(range(0,1002),1001)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**About the first question:**

If you start the recursion as `search(lst[0:], key)` then you will enter an infinite recursion. Notice that for the recursion to stop you need to have each time a smaller list than before and that is the case with `search(lst[1:], key)`.

Also, as to why the first element is treated separately, notice you need to perform the comparison against `key` one element at a time, and that element is `lst[0]`.

So in this recursion, you divide the problem in two: (1) you check if some element of the list is equal to your key (this element is always the first element of the **current** list), and (2) a recursive call in the **rest** of the list.

**About the second question:**

This isn't a recursion:

```
selfref_list = [1, 2, 3]
selfref_list.append(selfref_list)
```

What those lines do is to create a list where the 4th element is the same list:

```
>>> selfref_list == selfref_list[3] 
True
```

But that is not related to recursion in functions.

Comment: I agree with your answer except for the last part where `selfref_list.append(selfref_list)`; OP was ambiguously asking about circular (cyclic) objects.

Comment: I think you need to look more broadly into the theme of recursion in languages. The conjugation of the concept does provide for the opportunity to not discus this question fully, but I would rather people really think about this one. Also this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, in the first line, `def search(lst, key)`. that is, every time the function is called, it will use the entire `lst` which is the same as `lst[0:]`. Now, the reason that you have

```
    else: # recursive case: advance to next element in list
        return search(lst[1:], key)
```

is to define what happens after the current first element has been traversed. Basically, it says, "after the first element has been checked, continue with checking the rest of the elements starting with the next element."

Answer (score 1):

**Why is the first element treated separately:**
 Because each instance of your recursive method does part of your job, the function must check an element from the array. The First element or `lst[0]` will be the only element left when you call the function for a list with one element so why not just check it every time the list isn't empty?

**Why is this a recursion?**

`selfref_list = [1, 2, 3]
selfref_list.append(selfref_list)`

In the most literal sense it is not recursion. Rather the data type is recursive, meaning that an object may include itself in an instance of the same object type. Or in more formal mathematical terms a node type in a grammar tree is permitted to have an outgoing edge to another node of similar type...

[recursive grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_grammar)

[recursive data Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type)

[image: Notice that the top list contains a similar list.]